# Okapi : convert xls to xliff

Tags: localization, translation, xliff

I need to create a Rainbow Translation Kit of type Generic XLIFF from xls file. I am able to create xliff from xlsx, but how do I go about doing it for xls.
Converting xls to xlsx is also acceptable (how to convert?).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

XLS is a binary format. And as such really difficult to read.
The only way I know that converts an XLS to a XLSX is Aspose:

http://www.aspose.com/downloads/cells-family/java

You could install Excel and use COM Automation, but that is not recommended on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **xliff2po** and **po2xliff**.

You could look for the toolkit here : [URL of the toolkit](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/)

Answer (score 0):

Okapi doesn't support direct XLS processing, so the best bet is to convert XLS to XLSX and then process that with the Okapi OpenXML filter.  The best case would be to do the conversion with Excel itself, but if that's not an option, you could look at using Google Spreadsheets as an intermediate, or something like Apache POI.